# failure installing MikTex 2.9

Tags: miktex, installing

I have a similar failure installing MikTex 2.9., with or without admin right, 
it is almost the same failure and output log using:

- basic-miktex-2.9.6219.exe
- basic-miktex-2.9.6069-x64
- or basic-miktex-2.9.6219-x64

With the first two ones I have this log

```
An error occurred:
 source file: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\win\winFile.cpp
 source line: 488
 message: Permission denied: path="C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/enc/dvips/base/6w.enc"
 info: path="C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/enc/dvips/base/6w.enc
```

Trying to install it with admin rights I got the same error but in "C:\Program Files".

with the third one the log is this one:

```
An error occurred:
 source file: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\win\winFile.cpp
 source line: 488
 message: Permission denied: path="C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-cs.enc"
 info: path="C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-cs.enc"
```

Assuming there is no problem with all installers and the difference between "/" and "\" I see in the path ("MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/enc") is harmful. What the origin of the failure could be and how could I work it around.

Comment: Did you try with admin privileges?, and where exactly you mean '\' and '/', because as I see there are lot of places that has this. So could you specify where exactly you mean?. It would make the lot more easier. :)

Comment: I have no admin privileges, but I had it running before without a problem. I am using it to complement RStudio to produce a markdown output in pdf. The pdf fails, but the html does not.

Comment: Similar to what, I'm sorry?

Comment: good point! I changed, but similar in both compiled installer

Comment: The slashes/backslashes are normal and harmless. I can't tell you why you get a permission denied error -- perhaps a virus protection, a firewall, a timeout ... You could try to install miktex somewhere else -- I have some doubts that AppData is a good place to put the main miktex tree.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer, I tried to intall MikTex somewhere else, but it failed at the same step

Comment: I have tried to install it with admin privileges and I got the same error "Permission denied... .../dvips/base/6w.enc"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the antivirus that blocks the .enc files. I am not sure why did not block it the first time I installed MikTex, but eventually it did.

I thought it was some problem with MikTex so I tried to update it, it failed it, so I tried to install it again and it failed it also. While I was extracting the file for the portable installation I realized that all .enc file were blocked, the antivirus said "Block CryptolockerVirus" for all .enc files.

Would an exception work? I hope so